# Multiplicity of eigenvalues of adjacency operator and dimension of represenations

Tags: representation-theory, cayley-graphs

Let $G$ be a finite group, $S\subset G$ a symmetric subset of generators of $G$ (symmetric means $S=S^{-1}$), and $Cay(G,S)$ the corresponding Cayley graph.  I'm trying to show that if the minimal dimension of non-trivial $G$-represenations is $m$, then every non-trivial eigenvalue of the adjancesy operator on the graph has multiplicity of $m$ at least. I tried to take an eigenvalue with multiplicity of $m$ and use the corresponding eigenvectors to construct a presentation of dimension $m$, but it didn't work (probably because it is a stronger claim than the question itself). Any other ideas will be welcomed.

Comment: Why are you trying to show this? Were you asked to? If so, by whom/what? Or do you just suspect the connection?

Comment: h.w. in representation theory course

Comment: Could you tell us the book used or a bit more about the course? Knowing the sort of things one can assume known is helpful.

Comment: I don't want to do your homework for you, but here is a hint:  Consider the space of complex valued functions on (or alternatively formal linear combinations of) vertices of the Cayley graph.  $G$ acts on its own Cayley graph so this is a representation of $G$.  Think about what representation this is, and what sort of map the adjacency operator is.